# Spark GroupBy While Maintaining Schema With Nulls

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a file with multiple JSON objects with the following schema:

```
{A: struct, B: struct, C: struct, D: struct}
```

with the property that values for `A` are never null; however, only one of `B, C,` or `D` can be non-null as well. For example, we would see something like this in the data frame:

```
+----+----+----+----+
| A  | B  | C  | D  |
+----+----+----+----+
|[..]|[..]|null|null|
|[..]|null|[..]|null|
|[..]|null|null|[..]|
+----+----+----+----+
```

I'm trying to group the data frame by `A` while maintaining the same schema/column structure of `(A,B,C,D)` such that all values in a given Row is non-null.

It may be possible that there could be a many-to-one relationship between `A` and any of `B,C,D`, in which case, I would change the schema to be

`{A: struct, B: list, C: list, D: list}`, but still maintain the column names.

I'm fairly new to Spark and Scala and can only structure my thoughts in a procedural manner where I traverse each row and hash on `A`, and build a complete row that way, but I'm not convinced it is a clean solution, nor am I able to express it effectively using the spark API.

Comment: https://spark.apache.org/docs/2.0.2/api/java/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.html#collect_list(org.apache.spark.sql.Column)

Is this what you might be looking for? Groupby A and then collect_list on B, C and D ?

Comment: @DominicEgger Thanks! I was just looking into that. One problem that may arise is that I can still have empty lists, no? Is it more efficient to filter those pre- or post-grouping? Also, would it be possible to change the schema for, say `B`?

that is, given that `B` is a nested struct with many fields, could I do a `collect_list` on `B` with only a subset of attributes?

Comment: empty lists should probably result in very little overhead. Frankly I'd prefer empty lists over nulls because it helps avoiding nullpointer exceptions. Do you have a special usecase where empty lists would be an issue?

Comment: Not really. For my use case, rows with empty lists do not have much meaning is all. It relates to the edit I had above where I'd like to do a more sophisticated `collect_list` where I can instead define a new `B'` that is a subset of `B`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comment section is a bit unwieldy so here's an example how you could do this

```
scala> case class Foo(a:String, b:String, c:String)
defined class Foo

scala> val ds = spark.createDataset(List(Foo("1","1",null), Foo("1",null,null), Foo("1","3",null), Foo("1", null, null)))
ds: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[Foo] = [a: string, b: string ... 1 more field]

scala> val collected = ds.groupBy(ds("a")).agg(collect_list(ds("b")).alias("b"), collect_list(ds("c")).alias("c"))
collected: org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame = [a: string, b: array<string> ... 1 more field]

scala> val filtered = collected.where(size(collected("b")) > 0 and size(collected("c")) > 0)
filtered: org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset[org.apache.spark.sql.Row] = [a: string, b: array<string> ... 1 more field]

scala> collected.show
+---+------+---+
|  a|     b|  c|
+---+------+---+
|  1|[1, 3]| []|
+---+------+---+


scala> filtered.show
+---+---+---+
|  a|  b|  c|
+---+---+---+
+---+---+---+
```

Answer (score 1):

```
val df = spark.createDataFrame(
     sc.parallelize(
         Seq(Row(1, 2, 3, 4), Row(1, 3, 4, null),
             Row(2, null, 4, null), Row(2, 2, 2, null))),
         StructType(Seq("A","B","C","D")
                        .map(StructField(_, IntegerType, true))
     )
)

df.show()
+---+----+---+----+
|  A|   B|  C|   D|
+---+----+---+----+
|  1|   2|  3|   4|
|  1|   3|  4|null|
|  2|null|  4|null|
|  2|   2|  2|null|
+---+----+---+----+

df
    .groupBy("A")
    .agg(collect_list('B) as "B", 
         collect_list('C) as "C",
         collect_list('D) as "D")
    .show

+---+------+------+---+
|  A|     B|     C|  D|
+---+------+------+---+
|  1|[2, 3]|[3, 4]|[4]|
|  2|   [2]|[4, 2]| []|
+---+------+------+---+
```

By default, collect_list does not collect null values, which is exactly what you want (you will get an empty list if all the values are null). Use collect_set to avoid duplicates.